# How to create a multi setup project in Advanced Installer

Tags: installation, advanced-installer

I’ve two MSI files that I want to be installed in one setup installation.
One is an application – EXE file and the other is a windows service that will start and stop the EXE file.

So, EXE file setup needs to be installed before the windows service.
First I create a project for the EXE file that generates a MSI file. After I create a project to the Windows Service application that generates other MSI. So far so good.
If I install each file separated it works well.

But, I’d like to have just one setup to install these two applications,
For what I read it seems that I need to add the EXE project (MSI file) to the Windows Service application project.

I already tried to add it on Prerequisites page as a Chained Package or as a Feature-based, but only installs the EXE project. The Windows Service is never installed.

What mistake I’m doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the correct way. You can modify the project that installs your EXE file, to also install and start the service.

Your project that installs the EXE now just contains the file in Files and Folders page. The new step is to go to Services page and add a [new service installation.](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-java-service.html#define-service)

The linked example from above is a for a Java application, but he same can be applied to any other executable file.

Comment: Following your answer I just need to do one more step that was to add to Files and Folders the Windows Service files to let me choose the file in Services page > Services to Install

Comment: that is correct. I though you already had the file there, since you said you had the MSI installing that file. Probably I misunderstood you